# How to accept a single, default field in a Symfony form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a REST API written in Symfony3, with help from the FOSRestBundle.

It makes use of Symfony form classes for data input (POST, PATCH, PUT actions), which works great for almost all endpoints.

However I have a child endpoint that sets up relations using a form with a single collectionType. A POST request body looks like this:

```
curl http://localhost/documents/100/related -d @- <<REQUEST_BODY
{
  "related": [
    {"id": 14},
    {"id": 23}
  ]
}
REQUEST_BODY
```

However I would like to ommit the "related" field name as this information is already in the URI and seems redundant here. I would like to adjust the form to accept data like this:

```
curl http://localhost/documents/100/related -d @- <<REQUEST_BODY
[
    {"id": 14},
    {"id": 23}
]
REQUEST_BODY
```

But cannot see how to make a Symfony form behave in this way?

To clarify, I want to accept a single form field without having to specify the name of that field in a JSON request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while back. What worked for me, was to use the *form factory* to create a *named form* with an empty name, like so (example when inside a typical controller):

```
/** @var $formFactory FormFactory */
$formFactory = $this->get('form.factory');

$form = $formFactory->createNamed('', $type, $data, $options);
```

Be aware that a form configured like this will *consume* all POST (or GET) data. So, if you can't ensure that only the required data will be present, you might need to use [`allow_extra_fields`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Not come across this method before but seems to do the job nicely.